# OpenGLES 3 iOS object displaying as triangles and not filled

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es

I am trying to display a banana in iOS using OpenGLES. I am pretty sure I have everything set up properly, but when the app starts, the banana isn't being drawn correctly. It shows up like this:

The banana object I am trying to display is from the sample banana.h provided by [obj2opengl](https://github.com/HBehrens/obj2opengl).

[App running on iPhone 5 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YThyC.png)

Here is the setup:

```
    - (void)setupGL {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self loadShaders];

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
    self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bananaVerts), bananaVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_textureCoords);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureCoords);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(bananaTexCoords), bananaTexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Vertex attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    // Normal attribute
    /*glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);*/
    // TexCoord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

    [self loadTexture];

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And this is the drawing method:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self calculateMatrices];

    glUseProgram(_program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture.name);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(_program, "texture1"), 0);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(_program, "viewMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, _modelViewMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(_program, "projectionMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, _projectionMatrix.m);

    glBindVertexArray(_vertexArray);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, bananaNumVerts);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

varying vec2 TexCoord;
varying vec3 vNormal;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = viewMatrix * projectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

EDIT:

I fixed the problem by changing the draw command to

```
GL_LINES
```

instead of

```
GL_TRIANGLES.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `glVertexAttribPointer` looks wrong.

You need to call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` of the relevant buffer before calling `glVertexAttribPointer` to reference it. Currently you are referencing the `_textureCoords` buffer for both position and texture coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it, but the problem still remains.